# How to keep track of logic flow in huge volume of codes

Tags: javascript, optimization, coding-style

I am creating a statistics page for My website which bring reports in form of charts.It have a JavaScript file which has some 500 to 800 lines of codes and sends nearly 5 to 8 ajax request to fetch datas. As the no of lines in the code increases it becomes more difficult to keep track of what is really happening.

I am unable to keep track which part of code is implementing a particular business logic.

Is there a tool or better way to document the code and the business logic which it implements some thing handy which I may refer during editing code so that I will keep track of activities a code will carry out at a point of time.

For eg check the link below for documentation of test report. Some similar way of combining business logic and functions(codes) to keep track of code would do great.

[Click Here](http://www.9lessons.info/2011/07/how-to-prepare-better-test-report.html)

Thanks for reply

Comment: To check the ajax requests you can use Chrome devtools.

Comment: Yes I Use that.Speaking about Editing it would be really gr8 if we have some tool like one which we used for documenting database schema to keep track of which part of code is implementing what business logic

Comment: Some documentation like one in below link would also do gr8. http://www.9lessons.info/2011/07/how-to-prepare-better-test-report.html

Comment: Can't it help to split up your javascript into logical smaller chunks?

Comment: There are a number of ways to split up code into more manageable chunks.  Everything from creating Objects for each main function, or creating modules with well-separated concerns.  ON a higher level, tools like `requirejs` can even only load what you need.  That said, this question is so broad that it isn't really suitable for StackOverflow.